# Angular directive no data in link function's $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive which sets the `test` variable to `abc` in the `init` function of the controller. However in my link function the `test` variable is undefined.

```
angular.module('module')
       .directive('directive', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'dt',
    controller: Controller,
    ...
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    ...
    scope.dt.initialize = function() {
      initializeDirective(scope, element, attrs);
    }
  }

  function initializeDirective(scope, element, attrs) {
    // not able to get scope.dt.test, it's undefined
    console.log(scope.dt.test); // undefined
  }
}

function Controller() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = '123';
  vm.create = function(data, config) {
    vm.test = 'abc';
    vm.initialize();
  }
  ...
}
```

And in another JavaScript file code that creates the directive. It is calling the `create` function

```
// JavaScript in another file that inits the directive
var directive = vm.get(...);
vm.create(vm.data, config);
```

From my understanding, `scope.dt` should be automatically injected to the link function because of the `controllerAs`, which it is but `scope.dt.test` does not exist.

**EDIT**

I put the `test` variable outside the `create` function and set it to `123`. The `console.log` now logs `123`, which is not what I want (I want `abc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your link function executes when the directive is compiled. If you call create after that you are to late and the variable 'test' is stil undefined at the moment of compilation.

What you probably want is specify the value as an attribute on your directive:

```
angular
    .module('module')
    .directive('directive', myDirective);

    function myDirective(){
        return {
            link: link,
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: 'dt',
            controller: controller,
            scope: {
               test: '@'
            }
        };

        function controller(){
            var vm = this;
            // at this point vm.test is set to the value specified.
        }

        function link(scope, elem, attrs){
            // U can use scope.dt.test, scope.test or attrs.test here
        }
    }
```

Use this directive as:

```
<my-directive test="{{someValue}}"></my-directive>
```

Comment: plz also post a solution - otherwise this is not a correct answer

Comment: @Bas thanks for your comment, I placed the 'test' variable outside the function but it does not return the correct results, please take a look at my edit

Comment: @Dan no, that would make no difference. See my editted answer to see a possible solution.

Comment: @messerbill there was nothing wrong with that answer since the current solution is just not right in it's setup. Hard to post a solution that way. Tried anyways.

Comment: @Bas 'test' is hard coded in this example but it should be dynamic. Is there a way to do this if it was dynamic?

Comment: @BasSlagter this solution looks much better - and i know that your answer was not too bad before, so i did not downvote it.

Comment: @dan you probably want a service or something in between to get your data.